# Ignore a test based on environment variable

Tags: rust

There are a few tests that's running locally but not on Github workflows. I've spent quite some time but not able to debug and fix them. For now, I want to ignore them on ci/cd but run them locally. Since, Github provides a handy environment variable `CI`, which always remains true, can I use that to ignore test?

I don't want to wrap the whole function code under `if(env::var("CI").is_ok())`. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 6):

One way you could go about doing this is by adding a feature to your `Cargo.toml` file, like `ci` or something similar. And then have your GitHub action compile with that feature enabled, and have a conditional compilation attribute on the tests in question.

To do this, you would first add a new feature to your `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[features]
ci = []
```

Then in your Rust code on a test you could write something like this:

```rust
#[test]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "ci", ignore)]
fn test_some_code() {
    println!("This is a test");
}
```

Now locally if you run `cargo test` you will see the test run, but if you run `cargo test --features ci` you will see the test shows `ignored`, like below:

[image]

Now you just have to change your GitHub action to compile with this feature. If your action looks something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build
      run: cargo build --verbose
    - name: Run tests
      run: cargo test --verbose
```

Then add `--features ci` to the end of both the cargo build and cargo test commands.

For more information on conditional compilation, this is in the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html

For more information on features in Cargo, this is in the Cargo book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html

Answer (score 3):

To add to pokeyOne's answer, you can include a build script that checks for the `CI` environment variable and enables a `ci` feature when it's present. To do this, you would add this `build.rs` to your project root:

```rust
fn main() {
    if std::env::var("CI").is_ok() {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=feature=\"ci\"");
    }
}
```

Note that build scripts are only run on clean builds, so to test this locally you'll need to run `cargo clean` between runs (this won't be an issue on CI since you're doing a clean build there).

```
$ cargo test       # run all tests
$ cargo clean      # make sure build.rs is re-run...
$ CI=1 cargo test  # skip CI tests
```

Features are a special type of `--cfg` flag, used for conditional compilation. Instead of using a feature, you could instead use a single identifier `--cfg` flag, like so:

```rust
// build.rs
fn main() {
    if std::env::var("CI").is_ok() {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=ci");
    }
}

// src/main.rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  // ..(snip)..

  #[test]
  #[cfg(not(ci))]
  fn breaks_on_ci() { ... }
}
```

This `build.rs` is equivalent to running

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="--cfg ci" cargo test
```

You can read more about build scripts, `--cfg` flags, and conditional compilation in the Rust book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and put together a little macro that checks that an environment variable is defined. If not, the code block (e.g. a test) will be skipped.

The test `some_test` will not be compiled if `SOMEENVIRONMENTVARIABLE` is not defined at compile time.

```
#[needs_env_var(SOMEENVIRONMENTVARIABLE)]
#[test]
fn some_test() {
    assert!(1 == 1);
}
```

https://crates.io/crates/needs_env_var